# SP 2007 Checked Out document discrepency

Tags: 2007, document

In SP 2007 Doc Library, we created a view that displays only checked out documents by user. However, the user is seeing a different document count than what others are seeing.
They see 1261 documents checked out and others see that they have 21 documents checked out. What could be the cause of this? The rule is very simple. Under 'Filter' it has:
Show the items when column
'Checked Out To'
Is not equal to
*Blank*

[image]
[image]

Comment: This may have to do with permissions, or being able to only Read and others can see drafts when there is no published version. Can you check permissions and versioning settings?

Comment: thanks, Mike!
We think it's the Explorer View that's causing the issue. When you upload a document using it, it gives it a version of '0.1' and only the person who uploaded it can see it until they check it in. We think that the users have been uploading the documents and not checking them in. So they see a larger count for checked out documents than anyone else that views what they have checked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may have to do with permissions, or being able to only Read and others can see drafts when there is no published version.